# Using Canvas Theme from Themeforest in Rails 4 App

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, themes

I'm trying to build a Rails 4 app using the [Canvas](http://themeforest.net/item/canvas-the-multipurpose-html5-template/9228123) theme from Themeforest and it's kickin' me arse.

I've searched several ways to put the CSS/JS in the right folders and I even had success with it, using this [tutorial](https://railsmania.com/en/lessons/project-bob-adding-bootstrap-theme/). Yeah!

When I try to use the same method with the Canvas theme, all hell breaks loose. The theme comes with the following:

```
Canvas-Theme/

 - css/
    - fonts/
        - (a bunch of custom fonts)
    - animate.css
    - bootstrap.css
    - calendar.css
    - camera.css
    - colors.css
    - colors.php
    - dark.css
    - font-icons.css
    - fonts.css
    - magnific-popup.css
    - nivo-slider.css
    - responsive.css
    - vmap.css
 - images/
    - (a bunch of images)
 - js/
    - canvas.slider.fade.js
    - events-data.js
    - functions.js
    - jquery.calendario.js
    - jquery.camera.js
    - jquery.elastic.js
    - jquery.gmap.js
    - jquery.js
    - jquery.mousewheel.min.js
    - jquery.nivo.js
    - jquery.vmap.js
    - plugins.js

 - (tons of HTML templates)
 - style.css
 - style.less
```

In my Rails app, I'm using the default install (except mysql) which includes the following gems:

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.7'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
```

I droped all the CSS files under

```
app/assets/stylesheets/
```

and all the JS in

```
app/assets/javascript/
```

I also created a fonts folder and put the included fonts in there

```
app/assets/fonts/
```

Here is my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Here is my application.css

```
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
```

Now, there was that one 'style.css' file in the root of the Canvas-Theme folder that I've dropped in the stylesheets folder. Not sure if that was the right thing to do.

After all of that, I copy and pasted one of the HTML files into my index.html.erb files and I'm basically getting a blank screen. I know I need to change the paths for the images but I should at least see something.

A couple questions,

- Do I get rid of the 'jquery.js' file that came with the theme because Rails is including it already?
- Should I use the bootstrap gem instead of the included 'bootstrap.css'?

Need to get passed this tomfoolery!

Comment: I got it to show something. There was a line of HTML that was clearing everything before it got a chance to show anything. Still, it's not pretty.

Comment: I'm getting a little further but it doesn't seem like the JavaScript is working at all.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed. So it turns out that it's how I'm ordering my JavaScript. I ended up changing my appilcation.js file to this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require functions
```

I moved the 'functions.js' file to the vendors/assets/javascript folder so it would be included last after the tree was included. Seems to be doing the trick. Moral of the story, be mindful of CSS/JS order. But you knew that but who am I talking to because I've basically just commenting on my own thread. Well, I'm out.

Comment: Glad to see someone else going through the frustrations. Incidentally, I have had a similar issue, which I have forcefully resolved by removing turbo links. Functions.js continue to fail. Just thought I bring this up in case you have further issues transitioning to other pages.

Comment: @Craigfoo, if you felt so inclined to share your boilerplate app on github, I would certainly be super appreciative, if you found the time. It would basically be "Canvas on Rails" starter app. (Although, come to think of it, I'm not sure how the canvas theme licensing would accept this.. actually posting the code should be okay i think, it's if people have a license to use it that would be what they need to take care of). You could always do "insert canvas file here". Well just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Craigfoo,
your solution helped me to go further. To enable the slider to work I didn't change the appilcation.js but I moved the functions.js file to the vendors/assets/javascript folder and changed the views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Canvas</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

  <%= yield %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'functions', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

</body>
</html>
```

I needed to precompile. Add in config/initializers/assets.rb the line:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( functions.js )
```